# How to run bash script inside another bash script where path has spaces?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, scripting

Hi I am trying to call a bash script from inside another bash script. Here's how the structure is:

script a:
a.sh <pass_a_path_with_spaces>

example:

`a.sh /Users/Desktop is this/`

Now I want to run a.sh inside b.sh like this
script b:

`b.sh <pass_a_path_with_spaces>`

example:

`b.sh`

```
path="/Users/Desktop\ is\ this/"
script_a="/Users/Desktop\ is\ this/a.sh"
source "$script_a" "$path"
```

However when I run this, I get this error:
/Users/Desktop\ is\ this/a.sh: No such file or directory

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You're "double-quoting". Remove the backward slashes: `"/Users/Desktop is this/"`

Comment: Have you considered using `Command Substitution` and relative paths? You could nest several commands with `$()`
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: @mugglewithastruggle: You are overdoing: *Either* escape each space with a backslash, *or*  put the string between quotes, not both. Example: `path='/Users/Desktop is this'`. Small warning: I would not name the variable _path_; maybe one day you will make a switch from bash to zsh, and _path_ has a special meaning in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `double quote` around the directory with the spaces to preserve the name of the directory, something like this:

```
b.sh

  path=/Users/"Desktop is this"/
  script_a=/Users/"Desktop is this"/a.sh
  source "$script_a" "$path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a quote `'` because this is lateral and the string inside the single quote, will  not be changed when the variable is used.

for example,
a.sh '/Users/Desktop is this/'